# I installed python 2.7 on RHEL6 server, want to go back to 2.6

Tags: rhel, yum, python, rpm

I am on RHEL6 and I installed python27 using these commands:

```
sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- http://people.redhat.com/bkabrda/scl_python27.repo >> /etc/yum.repos.d/scl.repo'

sudo yum install python27

scl enable python27 bash
```

Now when i use which python, it comes up with:

```
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python
```

and python -V is:

```
Python 2.7.5
```

However I want to go back to 2.6. Is there a way I get uninstall or remove python 2.7 from my machine? As it was installed through a package?

Comment: You could use the EPEL-repository, and then do sudo yum install python26 to install python 2.6

Comment: Try to do `ls -l /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python*` and `ls -l /opt/rh/python*` and give back your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you installed is Python packaged as [Software Collection](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/). This way you can have system python and python27 side by side.

If you open one terminal and you run:

```
scl enable python27 bash
```

then it will start new bash where python is used from /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python

But if you open another terminal, then python will be used from /usr/bin/python

In fact is is inteded that you can run

```
scl enable python27 ./yourscript.py
```

and it will be run using python27, while

```
./yourscript.py
```

will be run using your system python